# Sql query without using inner join in it

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark Dataset inputDS `Dataset<Row>` like below

```
  +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
  |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
  +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
  |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
  |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
  +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Generated by **STEP 1**

```
Dataset<Row> inputDS = readInput.groupby("thingId","controller","module","variableName").agg(max(struct("time","value")).as("time_value_struct")).select("thingId","controller","module","variableName","time_value_struct.*");
```

**Expected output**

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

`Max(time)` column for that `thingId,controller,module and variableName`

End goal is to get last updatedvalue for every thingId, controller,module and variableName based on MAX(`time`) column.

**Code**

```
inputDS.createOrReplaceTempView("intermediate");

Dataset<Row> outputDS = spark.sql("select B.time,A.thingId,A.controller,A.module,A.variableName,A.value from intermediate A 
inner join (select thingId,controller,module,MAX(time)time from intermediate group by thingId,controller,module) B 
on A.thingId=B.thingId and A.controller=B.controller and A.module=B.module");
```

SQL query works as expected but using `inner join` doesn't look efficient

1)  Is there is any other efficient way we could get the expected output without inner join or equivalent where condition.

2) it would be great if we could able to get the expected output from **STEP 1**

```
 Dataset<Row> intermediate = inputDS.groupby("thingId","controller","module","variableName").agg(max(struct("time","value")).as("time_value_struct")).select("thingId","controller","module","variableName","time_value_struct.*");
```

Comment: Short of using analytic functions, which might not even possible is Spark SQL, your current join query is completely valid.  If performance is an issue, then look into ways to tune the join query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, spark does allow analytic functions, you can take a look on this link: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation of your current join query, which relies on `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT time, thingId, controller, module, variableName, "value"
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY thingId, controller, module
                                   ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM intermediate
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Analytic functions usually can beat out an older school approach such as a join.